# Hyperledger Composer setting up connection.json

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Hi thank you for all guys watching this article.

Cuz I want to use Hyperledger composer, I deployed orderer, peer, ca and other things. And I got success until creating channel and joining channel
(I believe that this is true cuz I finished making channels, joining peers to join that channel, installing and instantiating chaincode.)

So after that I did

"composer network install" command and I got error that there is no response from peers.
(And "Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF")
So I started to think that there is a problem on the file named "connection.json". But I don't know specifically how to edit that file.

I got response like below commanding "docker service ls" and "docker network inspect fabric"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prDch.png)

and my connection.json file looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJU66.png)

And I referred to this page to do Hyperledger Fabric on multiple hosts.

https://medium.com/@malliksarvepalli/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-using-docker-swarm-and-compose-f4b70c64fa7d

And this is the screenshot after installing business network

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZuV1.png)

Comment: TLS set to true or false ? and can you paste the peer logs also

Answer (score 2):

I think your fabric network is not running!

open a terminal and go to your fabric-dev-servers directory and ./startFabric.sh

if you facing any error there, like some container already exists do ./teardownFabric.sh first and then run above start command again.

once a network is running successfully then you need to create admin card by running ./createPeerAdminCard.sh

Comment: I successfully deployed Hyperledger Composer locally.(As you said, doing tutorial from Hyperledger Composer.) And I have no problem about that. I have problem when I do those on multiple hosts

Comment: okay, I got it. Sorry for the misunderstanding. So, can you provide a screenshot of composer network install error log ??

Comment: I added the screenshot on the bottom of the article. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Could you confirm that all orderer, peers and CAs are successfully launched on each machine? 'docker ps' command shows which services are running. If you use 'docker ps -a', you can find which service is stopped.

---

From the all of docker-compose files, following container name should be listed by 'docker ps'

**orderer**
: orderer

**org1**
: ca1
: org1peer0
: org1peer1
: org1cli

**org2**
: ca2
: org2peer0
: org2peer1
: org2cli

Could you check this is correct?

Are you running this project on 3 machines or 3 cloud instances?

Comment: Thx for your reply. I did docker ps -a many times. And I got

1. peer1.org1.example.com-mycc
2. peer0.org1.example.com-mycc
3. fabric_org1peer1
4. fabric_org1peer0
5. fabric_ca1
6. fabric_org1cli
on one machine and on the other machine I got

1. fabric_orderer

and 'docker service ls' command shows that all the services are running

Comment: Frankly, I don't have experience about docker-swarm. Anyway, what is fabric_org1peer1 and fabric_org1peer0? Basic components of single org are **orderer, ca.org1, peer0.org1 and cli**. If it has **2 peers**, it will be **orderer, peer0.org1, peer1.org2, ca.org1 and cli**.  I have no idea what is fabric_org1peer1 and fabric_org1peer0.

Comment: I am looking at the docker-compose files of the project. It's not easy to write things, let me update through my answer.